# Format ps output. Show most memory heavy procs

Tags: ps

I am trying to get this output

```
  15%   abc
   7%   xyz
```

Running this command

```
ps axo pmem,args --sort  -pmem,-rss,-vsz | grep -v grep | 
                      grep  -e abc-e xyz | awk {'print $1'}
```

**How can I fit my `grep -e` arguments inside the output?**

Right now, predictably, I am only getting

```
15%
7%
```

You can assume that my Python script is creating the command on the fly and that I can modify it any way I need to.

Comment: Do you want to use that specific output for anything else? if not top/htop are pretty awesome

Comment: Basically, problem i am trying to find is a) find out what speficic apps are running as a given user (done), b) figure out whether box itself is running hot (done) and c) if box is running hot - are any of my apps (known) are responsible for it. What I need is to link `ps` output with app name

Comment: You've documented the expected *output*, could you put the *input* into the question also ?  Might be possible to lose the `grep`s and just do the matching within `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output example I think you need something like this:

```
ps axo pmem,args --sort -pmem,-rss,-vsz | awk '{print $1 "% " $2}' | grep -e abc -e xyz
```

Output should be:

```
15.0% abc
7.0% xyz
```